# cannot read property 'request' of undefined in electron

Tags: electron

When I try to use net.request, it returns an error "cannot read property 'request' of undefined in electron".

This is my code for main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {app, Menu} = electron;
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

var mainWindow = null;
app.on('ready', function(){         
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 500,
        height: 300 
    });    
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
    mainWindow.openDevTools(); 
    mainWindow.setMenu(null);   
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null;
    }); 


    const {net} = require('electron');
    const request = net.request('https://github.com');

    request.on('response', (response) => {
        console.log('STATUS: ${response.statusCode}')
        console.log('HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}');
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log('BODY: ${chunk}');
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.');
        });
    });
    request.end();  
});
```

I couldn’t find what went wrong. Can any suggest a solution for this? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't throw me error on `1.4.5`

[Highlight of comment:] 
Also, based on the release notes, `net` api is available only from `1.4.5` on https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v1.4.5

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. But i generates for me. what can be the reason?

Comment: 1.4.5, is that the version of electron?

Comment: My version is 1.3.4. How can i updrade to the latest?

Comment: how did you install your current version? is that a globally available (`-g`) or local installation? if it's local you can use `npm i` with `-g` flag.

Comment: *without `-g` flag

Comment: Great ;)
Also: based on the release notes, `net` api is available only from `1.4.5` on
https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v1.4.5

Comment: Thanks pregy for your great help.